# How can I get the pods resource usage via kubernetes go-client?

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I am trying to build an API, which can send back my pods' resource usage.
Looking at the [resources being used by the pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wPbP.png), I am not able to figure out the go-client API to send the request to. Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm pretty sure the kuberetes-dashboard uses XHR to obtain that data, so you can make the same requests your browser does, provided your `serviceAccount` has the correct credentials to interrogate the kubernetes-dashboard API
2. either way, that timeseries data surfaced by kubernetes-dashboard actually comes from heapster, not from the kubernetes API itself, so the kubernetes go-client wouldn't be involved but rather would be a query to the heapster `Service` (which IIRC does not require authentication, although it *would* require constructing the correct heapster query syntax, which kubernetes-dashboard is doing on your behalf)